# issues with snmp convert Gauge32 to interger

Tags: snmp, cisco, mib, oid

i have to try get a class-map bit rate traffic from router cisco ios xe

i get  a oid from cisco 
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/119031-technote-router-00.html

the OID of postbitrate is give me only Gauge32

**+-- -R-- Gauge     cbQosCMPostPolicyBitRate(11)**

so when my police traffic is under number : 4,294,967,295 , i get i correct value

but when the traffic go up of  4,294,967,295 bit 
of example my real policy-traffic bps is :4,665,204,000 
and when i try to get in by snmp i get value 376,176,704 (9 dig only)

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c ABCDED X.X.X.X iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.11
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.166.1.15.1.1.11.1298180580.131072 = Gauge32: 376176704
```

so how to convert a Gauge32 correct value when my traffic is go up of 4,294,967,295 bps

i know is 32-bit only can Handle maximum 4,294,967,295

but in cisco mib . and for policy-map postbitrate , is only return Gauge32 ...

Answer (score 2):

This is called the "SNMP counter wrap" condition (you can google it).
This is detailed in this Cisco page

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/26007-faq-snmpcounter.html

The only way for a management app to detect it is if the counter is smaller
than previously retrieved, at least one counter wrap occurred and you add 2^32-1 to
the latest value.

The alternative is to find the 64-bit counter, usually defined in a newer MIB.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have a Asr router is have many 64bit oid but for post policy bps just 32bit,

Comment: Then you WILL have to handle counter wrap, which is handled commonly by many network management apps.